# Shell Script do while flow

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script whose content is like:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_FILE='pgalldump.out'

echo $DB_FILE

DB_NAME=''

egrep -n "\\\\connect\ $DB_NAME" $DB_FILE | while read LINE
do

    DB_NAME=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}')
    STARTING_LINE_NUMBER=$(echo $LINE | cut -d: -f1)

    STARTING_LINE_NUMBER=$(($STARTING_LINE_NUMBER+1))

    TOTAL_LINES=$(tail -n +$STARTING_LINE_NUMBER $DB_FILE | \
    egrep -n -m 1 "PostgreSQL\ database\ dump\ complete" | \
    head -n 1 | \
    cut -d: -f1)

    tail -n +$STARTING_LINE_NUMBER $DB_FILE | head -n +$TOTAL_LINES > /backup/$DB_NAME.sql
done
```

I know what it is doing. But i have a doubt about the flow of do while in this case. At line `egrep -n "\\\\connect\ $DB_NAME" $DB_FILE | while read LINE` will egrep runs first or while . Because DB_NAME is empty at start of code.

Could anyone please explain the flow of do while in this case.

Comment: They run concurrently. However, the value you are grepping for will not change as the loop runs; the pattern is fixed before `egrep` starts.

Comment: ok, for first iteration what will be the value of _DB_NAME_ at **egrep -n "\\\\connect\ $DB_NAME" $DB_FILE | while read LINE**

Comment: DB_NAME will be as you set it, `DB_NAME=''`. AND the initial `egrep` command is only executed once, and feeds the `while` loop. So you'll need to find a different logic. You would be able to see this if you add `echo LINE=${LINE}XXX` as the first line of your `while` loop. Good luck.

Comment: `egrep` isn't iterated at all; it runs once, and the loop iterates over its *output*.

Comment: You have two entirely different variables named `DB_NAME`; the first one has the empty string as its value and is the one used to build the argument for `egrep`. The other is set inside the loop based on the most recently read line from the output of `egrep`.

Comment: It means if i write _egrep -n "\\\\connect" $DB_FILE | while read LINE_ instead of _egrep -n "\\\\connect\ $DB_NAME" $DB_FILE | while read LINE_ it will work the same